# inconsistent window.history.pushState uri encoding

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, pushstate, uriencoding

Take url address `www.somesite.com/@user1`

If I click on a good old fashioned `<a href...` hyperlink containing the link then the `@` is percent encoded to `%40` in the address bar.

If I use html5's `window.history.pushstate("object or string", "Title", 'www.somesite.com/@user1')` the `@` is *not* endocded - it instead shows as a '@' character.

This inconsistency troubles me. Mayhaps there is a way to make the behaviour consistent?

I have considered `encodeURIComponent('www.somesite.com/@user1')` for the pushstate url, but this also encodes the '/', and what I am hoping is for the `<a href...` hyperlink not encode the '@' symbol.

Comment: if you want the href version, just use it. i mean, if the urls come from anchors, grabbing a.href will be parsed while a.getrAttribute("href") will be raw un-encoded text. you can also document.createElement() a new A tag, set its .href, then read it's .href; the result will magically be valid and absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Using encodeURIComponent makes javascript assume there are no special HTTP characters to ignore.
extract the compnenet first:

```
var url = "www.somesite.com/@user1";
var atPos = url.indexOf('@');
var urlComp= url.slice(atPos);  //@user1
url = url.slice(0, atPos);
url += encodeURIComponent(urlComp); //"www.somesite.com/%40user1"
```